# How to make a page unavailable, if a variable didn't set?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Does there any way, to make a page unavailable for users, when a variable didn't set (without implementing any script, what is checking that variable)?

What if the user figures out the real path of the file, and open it?
Should I hide it well, or is there a simple way?

I am using Tomcat.

Comment: try.. catch block may come handy here, although it may not be recommended

Comment: It seems you want to add some behavior to an app without writing any code. That's not how computers work. You need to tell them what to do, with code.

Comment: I know I can do it with try carch, and other ways, but I dont want to use jsp skriptlet.

Comment: Can I set up something in deployment descriptor, to redirect the user to a specific page, if a session variable didnt set?